# Vigenere not encrypting my message in python

Tags: python, vigenere

So I have been working through an assignment that has use create a caesar and vigenere cipher.  I have already created the caesar cipher and am almost done with vigenere.  The problem I am having is in the actual encryption itself.  In my code I have got it all worked out punctuation and capitalization wise but when I just use print to test my function it just spits the same phrase back at me.  I am not sure if the problem is with my function reading the keyword before going through the rest of  the function or if I just missed something.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
def alphabet_position(letter):
    alphabet_pos = {'A':0, 'a':0, 'B':1, 'b':1, 'C':2, 'c':2, 'D':3,
'd':3, 'E':4, 'e':4, 'F':5, 'f':5, 'G':6, 'g':6, 'H':7, 'h':7, 'I':8,
'i':8, 'J':9, 'j':9, 'K':10, 'k':10, 'L':11, 'l':11, 'M':12, 'm':12,
'N': 13, 'n':13, 'O':14, 'o':14, 'P':15, 'p':15, 'Q':16, 'q':16,
'R':17, 'r':17, 'S':18, 's':18, 'T':19, 't':19, 'U':20, 'u':20, 'V':21,
'v':21, 'W':22, 'w':22, 'X':23, 'x':23, 'Y':24, 'y':24, 'Z':25, 'z':25
}
    pos = alphabet_pos[letter]
    return pos

def rotate_character(char, rot):
    if (ord(char) >= 97) and (ord(char) <= 122): # lowercase
        return chr(97+(alphabet_position(char)+rot)%26)
    elif (ord(char) >= 65) and (ord(char) <=90): # uppercase
        return chr(65+(alphabet_position(char)+rot)%26)
    else:
        return char

def encrypt(text, key):
    encrypted = []    
    starting_index = 0
    for letter in text:
    # if it's alphanumerical, keep it that way
    # find alphabet position
        rotation = alphabet_position(key[starting_index])
            # if it's a space or non-alphabetical character, append and move on
        if letter != alphabet_position:
            encrypted.append(letter)
        elif letter.isalpha():            
            encrypted.append(rotation(letter, rotation))             

    #if we've reached last index, reset to zero, otherwise + by 1
        if starting_index == (len(key) - 1): 
            starting_index = 0
        else: 
            starting_index += 1

    return ''.join(encrypted)
```

Comment: You never call `rotate_character()`. `rotation(letter, rotation)` is not valid, since `rotation` is a number.

Comment: `if letter != alphabet_position:` doesn't check whether `letter` is alphabetic or not.

Comment: `alphabet_position()` will get an error if the letter is not alphabetic. You don't have any check for this.

Comment: Instead of a dictionary, why not just use `ord(letter.lower)-97`?

Comment: We just learned about dictionaries in class so my teacher would prefer us to use a dictionary.  Doesn't `alphabet_position()` just reference the first function that only has letters?  Or does that function not get called there?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
  if letter != alphabet_position:
```

Since alphabet_position is a **function**, it is always different from letter. So, you execute the next instruction, which appends `letter` as-is to the result.

Comment: So does that mean it is something as simple as changing that conditional?  Or do I need to rework that statement and some above it?  I feel like the line above the conditional is wrong also since it has that function in it.

Comment: As Barmar pointed above, you have some other problems in your code, but this one is directly responsible for your output being identical to input.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if letter != alphabet_position:
```

does not tell if `letter` is alphabetic. It simply compares the value of `letter` (a string) to the value of `alphabet_position` (a function), and they'll never be equal. So it always runs that code block, which just adds the letter to `encrypted`.

You can use the `string.isalpha()` function for this.

```
if not letter.isalpha():
```

You could also make the `alphabet_pos` dictionary a global variable, and use:

```
if letter not in alphabet_pos:
```